# Access members of parent controller from UIPopoverController

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller, member

How can I access the members of the controller that is calling a UIPopoverController inside that UIPopoverController?

The controller calling the UIPopoverController is set as a delegate on the popup (not sure if this helps me):

```
self.popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:theView];
[self.popover setDelegate: self];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You access them in the same way as you access members from any other view controller: you need a reference to the parent view controller. For example, you could have a member variable on your popover view controller that points to the parent view controller. (You would want to make such a reference weak or unretained.) This member is often a "delegate" of the popover view controller.

You could set this on your `theView` before presenting it, or pass it to its initializer.

(I'm not sure, but you could also try looking at `parentViewController` or `presentingViewController` of the popover view controller.)

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use properties

`@property double ivar` (as I remember) This way you'll call it that way.

```
double test = self.popover.ivar;
```

or maybe `double test = [self.popover ivar]` . Both should work.

To do this, make sure you `@synthesize ivar;` in the .m file of the master controller or make a method as a getter

For the method, if it's a double,

```
- (double)ivar
{
     return 5;
}
```

is an example. If you're returning an instance variable, it's better to return a copy of it. Example:

```
return [ivar2 copy];
```

If you're using the method way, be sure that the method is the same name as the variable in the .h file.

Hope I helped!

EDIT: Replace that "double" thing with UIView, just saying